# How can I split long tables in Emacs org-mode latex export?

Tags: longtable, emacs, org-mode

In LaTeX, when tables get very long one can use the longtable package. But what about org-mode latex export in Emacs? Is it possible to have org-mode split long tables?

Comment: I don't think this should have been migrated.  It's not a latex question, but an emacs/org question. You need to check on how to specify the table type for your org-mode tables; this is done somehow in setting the org-mode export.

Answer (score 8):

Straight from the org-mode manual:

For LaTeX export of a table, you can specify a label and a caption (see Images and tables). You can also use the ATTR_LaTeX line to request a longtable environment for the table, so that it may span several pages, or to change the default table environment from table to table* or to change the default inner tabular environment to tabularx or tabulary. Finally, you can set the alignment string, and (with tabularx or tabulary) the width.

https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-LaTeX-export.html